# Что это такое? PyTelegramBotAPI Telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Я копирую-создаю бот аукцион для русских пользователей на языке питон с использованием телебота. Столкнулся с проблемой реализации ниже показанного функционала. Бот присылает главное меню аукциона, где есть кнопка опубликовать. При нажатии на неё, пользователь может выбрать чат, куда хочет опубликовать аукцион. После выбора чата в поле вода вставляется это:
@Auction24Bot 05509c9cc2c21419b46a908da40ce160b

И всё работает если отправить. Очень долго гуглю, смотрю документацию телебота. Либо я ищу не там, либо это делается другими методами. Вопрос что это? Может быть узнав, что это, я смогу отгадать сей ребус. Заранее благодарю.

[image: скрин1]
[image: скрин2]
[image: скрин3]
[image: скрин4]

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, вы спрашиваете о inline-запросах.

Создаются они примерно вот так:

```
keyboard_item = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Текст', switch_inline_query_current_chat='Текст для вывода')
```

При нажатии на эту кнопку будет выводиться @Auction24Bot Текс для вывода

Comment: В принципе это похоже и возможно будет использовано, но это не в полной мере всё объясняет. Интересно, что же всё-таки стоит за тегом(@Auction24Bot 05509c9cc2c21419b46a908da40ce160b).

Comment: Ну вы же используете какую-то библиотеку или чьи-то наработки для создания этого бота и не поясняете какие, это можно быть что угодно от сгенерированного токена сессии до зашифрованной или хэшированной команды.